# How can I use a regex match as a hash index in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm new to Ruby and I've run into an issue I can't solve.

I'm trying to use `gsub()` to match a pattern in a string, then use that match as an index into a hash. So far, I haven't been able to figure it out. Here's some code:

```
farm = { "pig_num" => 5, "horse_num" => 2, "cow_num" => 4}
assessment = "There are 'pig_num' pigs on this farm"

assessment.gsub(/'(.+?)'/, '\1') # => "There are pig_num pigs on this farm"
assessment.gsub(/'(.+?)'/, farm) # =>  "There are  pigs on this farm"
assessment.gsub(/'(.+?)'/, farm['\1']) # => TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String
assessment.gsub(/'(.+?)'/) { |key| farm[key] }
```

The first call to `gsub()` shows that I am matching the string I want.

The second call is an attempt to use the `gsub(pattern, hash)` flavor found at [the Ruby documentation site](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub]).

The third call is trying to reference the value using the match as an index.

The fourth is some fancy pants way I thought might work using a lambda/proc/block.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
assessment.gsub(/#{farm.keys.join('|')}/, farm)
```

Comment: Shishir, both yours and Kei's worked, but I gave you the green check because it's nice and short and confusing, just like Ruby should be. :)

Comment: You may wish to use `Regexp.union(farm.keys)` in place of `/#{farm.keys.join('|')}/`.

Answer (score 2):

```
farm = { "pig_num" => 5, "horse_num" => 2, "cow_num" => 4}
assessment = "There are 'pig_num' pigs on this farm"
```

---

**1**
"You may want to get the first object from farm hash but you need to tell from which hash you want to retrieve value". Otherwise, you need to use just Integer with String type like above.

```
assessment.gsub(/'(.+?)'/, '1')
```

---

**2**
when you `'gsub'` string, you get `'pig_num'` because you include `''` inside the regex so that result would be `"'pig_num'"`. However, the key of hash is `"pig_num"`. `"pig_num"` and `"'pig_num'"` are different. That is why you can't get data properly.

```
assessment.gsub(/'(.+?)'/, farm)
```

---

**3**
You can not point index inside blacket but hash key

```
assessment.gsub(/'(.+?)'/, farm["pig_num"].to_s)
```

---

**4**
As I said before, you get `"'pig_num'"` as key. If you print out the key value inside the block, you will see it. You need to change it to 'Pure key'. To get rid of quotation, you can use gsub again and make it empty instead of quotation. `gsub!`  is a destructive method which means modifies original value. If you use just `gusb`, the method returns modified value but the original key itself (in this situation) does not change. Otherwise, you need to assign the new value to another variable.

```
assessment.gsub(/'(.+?)'/) { |key| p key.gsub!("\'", ""); farm[key] }
```

I hope this answer is helpful for you. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I see on your code with regex match it will recognize `'pig_num'` is the hash key to find on `farm` hash. So you need to change your hash like
`farm = { "'pig_num'" => 5, "'horse_num'" => 2, "'cow_num'" => 4}` or you can change your regex. Example

```
farm = { "'pig_num'" => 5, "'horse_num'" => 2, "'cow_num'" => 4}
assessment.gsub(/'(.+?)'/, farm) # =>  "There are 5 pigs on this farm"
```

Or

```
farm = { "pig_num" => 5, "horse_num" => 2, "cow_num" => 4}
assessment.gsub(/pig_num/, farm) # =>  "There are '5' pigs on this farm"
```

Answer (score 0):

With some minor adjustments, your can use [`sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf)'s `%{name}` or `%<name>s`notation:

```
farm = { pig_num: 5, horse_num: 2, cow_num: 4 }
assessment = "There are '%{pig_num}' pigs on this farm"

sprintf(assessment, farm)
#=> "There are '5' pigs on this farm"
```